# how to block the accept method of socket when server is waiting for the connection from client?

Tags: java, client-server

how to block the accept method of socket when server is waiting for the connection from client?
my code is here:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444, 100);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
    System.exit(1);
}

Socket clientSocket = null;
try {
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    // Thread input = new InputThread(clientSocket.getInputStream());
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Accept failed.");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

I want to block the accept method which is waiting for the client..

Comment: That's what it does. Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: what do you mean by block? is it that you want "accept()" method to be wait for multiple client?

Answer (score 3):

[serverSocket.accept()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29) itself is blocking and  blocks until a connection is made.